# Biblatex: Changing number of authors listed in bibliography only for one section

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, author-number

I am using `biblatex` to print bibliographies per section. My style requires in general no article titles and maximum 3 authors per bibliography entry. Nevertheless in a specific section, I need to relax these limitations, and have article titles shown along with full list of authors. How can I achieve so?

The following are my current settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            maxnames = 3,
            firstinits=false,
            uniquename=init,
            autocite=superscript,
            style=nature,
            articletitle=false,
            natbib=true,
            defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my_publications.bib}

...
\begin{document}

\newrefsection
\section{First section}
Some text with \autocite{Ref:1}
...
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\section{Second Section}
%%------------------------
%% Here we want to relax no-show of article title max 3 authors
\settoggle{bbx:articletitle}{true} % Reset showing article name
<what should I do to reset maxbibnames??>

...

Some text with \autocite{Ref:1,Ref:2}
...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I think that a possible workaround could be by

```
\patchcmd{\blx@maxbibnames}{...}{...}{}{}
```

but I cannot complete the other fields correctly...

Comment: For future reference please note that your code does not constitute an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) - it can't be copied and compiled just like that. We are missing your `.bib` file, and the code is missing an `\end{document}` as well as a `\documentclass`. Please have a look at [this help about MWEBs](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) as well.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am going to edit it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but please note that your code is still not an MWE. We are still missing the `\documentclass` and have no idea bout your references in the `.bib` file.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I know that. But my `bib` file is a master file with thousands of references, I doubt it is useful here.

Comment: Of course the *whole* thing is not very useful, but you could just extract two example entries, which would be tremendously helpful. Or use `biblatex-examples.bib` as suggested in one of the links from my first comment. Have a look at the code in my answer and compare your non-MWE with the code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resetting the `maxname` option is surprisingly hard, because `maxnames` is kept very close to the entry itself. So I've come up with

```
\newtoggle{bbx:allnames}
\togglefalse{bbx:allnames}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iftoggle{bbx:allnames}{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}{}}
```

where you can use

```
\toggletrue{bbx:allnames}
```

in exact analogy to the `bbx:articletitle` toggle before `\printbibliography` to see all names. You can toggle back to the document default for the next `\printbibliography` with `\togglefalse{bbx:allnames}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            maxnames = 3,
            firstinits=false,
            uniquename=init,
            autocite=superscript,
            style=nature,
            articletitle=false,
            natbib=true,
            defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newtoggle{bbx:allnames}
\togglefalse{bbx:allnames}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iftoggle{bbx:allnames}{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}{}}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\section{First section}
Some text with \autocite{aksin}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\section{Second Section}
\toggletrue{bbx:articletitle}
\toggletrue{bbx:allnames}
Some text with \autocite{aksin,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```