# Biblatex: list all authors in fullcite

Tags: biblatex

I use  `maxbibnames = 5` to reduce the size of my (very long) bibliography. However, I also want to add a list of publications and for those all authors should be listed. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,maxnames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{paper1,
author   = {Name, Surname and Another, Name and Thethird, Name and Andthe, Last},
journal  = {JUR},
month    = {5},
title    = {{Title very good}},
year     = {2015}
}
@article{paper2,
author   = {Mane, Surmane and Amother, Mane and Thethird, Mane and Amdthe, Last},
journal  = {JUR},
month    = {5},
title    = {{Another brilliant title}},
year     = {2016},
maxnames = {1000000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
As first example citation here is \cite{paper1}. 
Here is another example citation \cite{paper2}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \fullcite{paper1}
    \item \fullcite{paper2}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to either

- change `maxnames` for one single citation, such as `fullcite`
- change `maxnames` for one printbiblography (`\printbibliography[maxnames = xxx]` doesn't seem to work
- change `maxnames` for one `refsection`

or actually any way to print a full citation with all authors, ... for some selected entries?

Comment: As usual: please add an compilable code and add one bib entry to test it ...

Comment: Maybe [Biblatex: Changing number of authors listed in bibliography only for one section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353477/35864) can help you.

Comment: But you could also use the fact that `maxnames` is also an entry-type option to print all names for certain `.bib` entries. Add `options = {maxnames=999}` to the relevant `.bib` entry.

Comment: If none of that helps, please prepare an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: I added a MWE. Addeing `maxnames` in the bib file doesn't work. but actually adding this switch as suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353477/35864 does solve the problem!

Comment: You might have misread my comment, you need `options = {maxnames=999}` and not `maxnames = {999}`, that should work. But if the solution in the other question worked for you, would you say your question is a duplicate?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get this. Yes this works like a charm! and yes you are right, I suppose it is a duplicate